# How to select the last column of numbers from a table created by FoldList in Mathematica

Tags: numbers, wolfram-mathematica, histogram

I am new to Mathematica and I am having difficulties with one thing. I have this Table that generates 10 000 times  13 numbers (12 numbers + 1 that is a starting number). I need to create a Histogram from all 10 000 13th numbers. I hope It's quite clear, quite tricky to explain.

This is the table:

```
F = Table[(Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 12];
Mu = -0.00644131;
Sigma = 0.0562005;
t = 1/12; s = 0.6416;
FoldList[(#1*Exp[(Mu - Sigma^2/2)*t + Sigma*Sqrt[t]*#2]) &, s, 
Xi]), {SeedRandom[2]; 10000}]
```

The result for the following histogram could be a table that will take all the 13th numbers to one table - than It would be quite easy to create an histogram. Maybe with "select"? Or maybe you know other ways to solve this.

Comment: Is this what you want: `Histogram[Last /@ F]`?

Comment: Thx a lot - I managed to find K = F[[All, 13]] but this is much better, thx!

Comment: `F[[All, -1]]` would work as well.

Comment: Just for future reference, a Mathematica specific exchange site exists: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can access different parts of a list using `Part` or  (depending on what parts you need) some of the more specialised commands, such as `First`, `Rest`, `Most` and (the one you need) `Last`. As noted in comments, `Histogram[Last/@F]` or `Histogram[F[[All,-1]]]` will work fine.

Although it wasn't part of your question, I would like to note some things you could do for your specific problem that will speed it up enormously. You are defining `Mu`, `Sigma` etc 10,000 times, because they are inside the `Table` command. You are also recalculating `Mu - Sigma^2/2)*t + Sigma*Sqrt[t]` 120,000 times, even though it is a constant, because you have it inside the `FoldList` inside the `Table`.

On my machine:

```
F = Table[(Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 12];
     Mu = -0.00644131;
     Sigma = 0.0562005;
     t = 1/12; s = 0.6416;
     FoldList[(#1*Exp[(Mu - Sigma^2/2)*t + Sigma*Sqrt[t]*#2]) &, s, 
      Xi]), {SeedRandom[2]; 10000}]; // Timing

 {4.19049, Null}
```

This alternative is *ten times faster*:

```
F = Module[{Xi, beta}, With[{Mu = -0.00644131, Sigma = 0.0562005,
      t = 1/12, s = 0.6416},
     beta = (Mu - Sigma^2/2)*t + Sigma*Sqrt[t]; 
     Table[(Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 12];
       FoldList[(#1*Exp[beta*#2]) &, s, Xi]), {SeedRandom[2]; 
       10000}] ]]; // Timing

{0.403365, Null}
```

I use `With` for the local constants and `Module` for the things that are other redefined within the `Table` (`Xi`) or are calculations based on the local constants (`beta`). [This question on the Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/8) will help explain when to use `Module` versus `Block` versus `With`. (I encourage you to explore the Mathematica StackExchange further, as this is where most of the Mathematica experts are hanging out now.)

For your specific code, the use of `Part` isn't really required. Instead of using `FoldList`, just use `Fold`. It only retains the final number in the folding, which is identical to the last number in the output of `FoldList`. So you could try:

```
FF = Module[{Xi, beta}, With[{Mu = -0.00644131, Sigma = 0.0562005,
      t = 1/12, s = 0.6416},
     beta = (Mu - Sigma^2/2)*t + Sigma*Sqrt[t]; 
     Table[(Xi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 12];
       Fold[(#1*Exp[beta*#2]) &, s, Xi]), {SeedRandom[2]; 
       10000}] ]];

Histogram[FF]
```

Calculating `FF` in this way is even a little faster than the previous version. On my system `Timing` reports 0.377 seconds - but such a difference from 0.4 seconds is hardly worth worrying about.

[image]

Because you are setting the seed with `SeedRandom`, it is easy to verify that all three code examples produce exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment an answer:
`Histogram[Last /@ F]`